# Shared memory addresses

Tags: c, linux, shared-memory

I am using C on Linux, and allocating 2 shared memory segments.

The first segment is created in a main program, then I call a subprocess and create the second segment.

In the subprocess, I place the address of the second segment in a pointer I set aside in the first segment.

Upon returning to the main program, when I attach to the second segment and compare the pointers (the one returned from shmat, and the one previously stored by the subprocess) I find they are different.

Is this expected?

Thanks, Mark.

Comment: And you don't post the code because ...?

Comment: "If shmaddr is NULL, the system chooses a suitable (unused) address
at which to attach the segment.", [shmat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/shmat.2.html)

Comment: IOW: if you want your memory to be mapped at the same address you have to ask for it explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is expected. Mapping to a common address in the virtual space of the two processes would be a very constraining limitation. Among others, the memory manager would have to know simultaneously which processes are willing to map, so that it finds a common free area. This would defeat the very principle of virtual memory (every process sees a blank address space), and cause configurations impossible to arbitrate.

Sharing at common addresses is indeed possible, but only makes sense when the mapping  is to some reserved section of the address space, so that it doesn't get mapped elsehow.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: hem, how do you work *without* pointers ?

Comment: Use your own indirection system! Share segment are to be shared and attaching them at fixed address is a problem, then you can't use raw pointers; implementing an indirection using a base address and offsets is easy and portable.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: Do you mean that adding indirection is a way to avoid pointers ??? There is no point avoiding pointers, I don' agree with your "general rule".

Comment: I mean you can always use a base pointer+arithmetic to be "independent" of location. If you want to be able to implement a linked list in a shared segment then you cannot use raw pointers in your structure, you need to implement relative pointing mechanism. This is what I would have mean. Your segment can be viewed as a big array you can index as you wish.

Comment: OK, so I will create and populate the second segment in the second procedure as before. But rather then using the second procedure to determine the address of the second segment, back in the first procedure, I will call shmat afterword to get the address of the second segment and go that route. This will add a small complication with indexing into the various tables (there are 3 tables of different length in the second segment,) but I think I can handle that.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: I agree with that. A clean way to do it by using... an array (and indexes). When you do so, the pointers indeed disappear from the syntax.

Comment: @CoolJavelin: it is a normal procedure to let every process use its own mapping and local address variables, as if working with a malloc (by the way, passing an address from one process to the other can raise synchronization issues).